# I can able to consume the https webservice with the ssl certificate being added to my JVM Truststore

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm able to consume HTTPS webservice with the ssl certiifcate being added to by JVM Trust store.I'm not getting any SSL Handshake error and How does connection is secure since i dont added any certificate. My tech stack is Sping boot, Spring MVC.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this a public webservice that you consume? Does it use a certificate, which is already trusted by the default CA in the JDK, maybe?

Comment: I see the root certificate is issued by the digicert which is a default CA in JDK  TrustSore. I have updated the question please see that.

Comment: Then you have your answer. If you would connect to a webservice, which is not issued by a trusted CA, then you would get a handshake error, until you add the issuing CA certificate in the trust store.